# Creating an uninstantiated copy of a RLMObject with all of its relationships also be uninstantiated

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Say I create a `RLMObject` that has a relationship, which I proceed to save in my realm database. After that is complete, I decide to call `initWithValues` on the newly created object and return this copied object to the front end for use. I noticed that the object it has a relationship with is still considered instantiated.

Is there a way to make it such that when I call `initWithValues` to create an uninstantiated copy of my object, to ensure all my properties are uninstantiated as well?

Comment: I guess you mean by `uninstantiated` that these objects are not persisted? That's what I based my answer on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin way to achieve that. You would need to create a standalone copy of the object yourself. Relationships could be cyclic, so that a generic solution for that would be non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured that would be the answer but was hoping to be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, for example, you can implement the `NSCopying` protocol in each managed class:

```
- (instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    //SomeClass *object = (SomeClass *)[super.class allocWithZone:zone];
    SomeClass *object = [SomeClass new];
    object->_isClone = YES;
    object->_name = self.name.copy;
    object->_age = self.age;
    return object;
}
```

Then, after removing the original, the copy remains available.

Can also be implement `NSCopying` protocol in category for `RLMResults`:

```
- (instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.count];
    for (RLMObject *object in self) {
        [array addObject:object.copy];
    }
    return array.copy;
}
```

Use case:

```
RLMResults *objects = [SomeObject objectsWhere:@"ANY nested.age < 99"];
NSArray<SomeObject*> *clones = objects.copy;
```